# How to prove the set of functions from the natural numbers to the natural numbers is equinumerous to the set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know how to prove that $^\omega$$\omega$ is uncountable, but how can we prove that it is, in fact, equinumerous to $\Bbb R$? Or at least that $^\omega$$\omega$ is equinumerous to $^\omega$$2$?

Comment: $2 < |\Bbb N| < |2^\Bbb N| \\ |2^\Bbb N| \le |\Bbb N^\Bbb N| \le |(2^\Bbb N)^\Bbb N| = |2^{\Bbb N \times \Bbb N}| = |2^{\Bbb N}| \\ |\Bbb N^\Bbb N| = |2^\Bbb N| = |\Bbb R|$

Comment: Ahh right, ok.. I knew it was something simple like this. Thanks.

Comment: Try proving each theorem used.